# How to create a conditional string value based on other columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a cartesian product dataframe like this:

```
soup = pd.DataFrame(data={'Beets': [   1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2,
                                    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2,
                                    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
                          'Carrots': [   0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                                      0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                                      0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                          'Potatoes': [   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]})
```

I need a new string column `[Recipe]` that lists all non-zero ingredients: their number followed by the letter code.

For example, the row with 1 beet, 0 carrots and 2 potatoes must show `1B, 2P`. Carrots *must be absent* from that string, because their number in that row is 0. A row with all three ingredients must show `2B, 2C, 1P`.

It would seem `.apply` is the most straightforward solution, but I didn't get very far.

My plan was to pass columns into the function like this:

```
def recipe_namer(b, c, p):
    name = []
    if b > 0:
        name.append[b.astype(str) + 'B, ']
    if c > 0:
        name.append[c.astype(str) + 'C, ']
    if p > 0:
        name.append[p.astype(str) + 'P, ']
    return name

soup['Recipe'] = soup.apply(recipe_namer(soup['Beets'], soup['Carrots'], soup['Potatoes']))
```

I was met with `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.` - which, fair enough.

After googling some more, I tried passing the whole dataframe:

```
def recipe_namer(s):
    name = []
    if s['Beets'] > 0:
        name.append[s['Beets'].astype(str) + 'B, ']
    if s['Carrots'] > 0:
        name.append[s['Carrots'].astype(str) + 'C, ']
    if s['Potatoes'] > 0:
        name.append[s['Potatoes'].astype(str) + 'P, ']
    return name

soup['Recipe'] = soup.apply(recipe_namer)
```

However, now I'm seeing `KeyError: 'Beets'`, as if it can't find the column I'm telling it to look at.

I'd appreciate any pointers as to how to move forward.

I'm aware that I'll have hanging commas at the end of the string even if this approach works, but that bridge should be relatively easy to cross once I get to it.

Answer (score 2):

I would [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) then filter the positive vegetables, concatenate the strings and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
codes = {'Beets': 'B', 'Carrots': 'C', 'Potatoes': 'P'}

soup['recipe'] = (soup.rename(columns=codes)
     .melt(ignore_index=False)
     .query('value>0')
     .pipe(lambda d: d['value'].astype(str)+d['variable'])
     .groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join).reindex(soup.index, fill_value='')
)
```

*NB. using a dictionary to maps the codes, but you could also use the first letter if needed (`soup.rename(columns=lambda x: x[0].upper())`).*

Or, using a custom function and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
codes = {'Beets': 'B', 'Carrots': 'C', 'Potatoes': 'P'}

def to_string(s):
    s = s[s>0]
    return ', '.join(f'{a}{b}' for a,b in zip(s.index, s))

soup['recipe'] = soup.rename(columns=codes).apply(to_string, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Beets  Carrots  Potatoes      recipe
0       0        0         0            
1       1        0         0          1B
2       2        0         0          2B
3       0        1         0          1C
4       1        1         0      1B, 1C
5       2        1         0      2B, 1C
6       0        2         0          2C
7       1        2         0      1B, 2C
8       2        2         0      2B, 2C
9       0        0         1          1P
10      1        0         1      1B, 1P
11      2        0         1      2B, 1P
12      0        1         1      1C, 1P
13      1        1         1  1B, 1C, 1P
14      2        1         1  2B, 1C, 1P
15      0        2         1      2C, 1P
16      1        2         1  1B, 2C, 1P
17      2        2         1  2B, 2C, 1P
18      0        0         2          2P
19      1        0         2      1B, 2P
20      2        0         2      2B, 2P
21      0        1         2      1C, 2P
22      1        1         2  1B, 1C, 2P
23      2        1         2  2B, 1C, 2P
24      0        2         2      2C, 2P
25      1        2         2  1B, 2C, 2P
26      2        2         2  2B, 2C, 2P
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is quite close to the result you're after, but you're missing a couple details.

The error you're obtaining is because you're [applying along the wrong axis.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Additionally, `.append()` is a method, and should thus use parenthesis.
I've also condensed a couple other details, though they are similar in function.

```py
import pandas as pd

soup = pd.DataFrame(data={'Beets': [ 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2,
                                    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2,
                                    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
                          'Carrots': [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                                      0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                                      0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                          'Potatoes': [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]})

def recipe_namer(s):
    name = []
    if s['Beets'] > 0:
        name.append(str(s['Beets']) + 'B')
    if s['Carrots'] > 0:
        name.append(str(s['Carrots']) + 'C')
    if s['Potatoes'] > 0:
        name.append(str(s['Potatoes'])+ 'P')
    return ', '.join(name)

soup['Recipe'] = soup.apply(recipe_namer, axis=1)
```

Which obtains:

```
    Beets  Carrots  Potatoes      Recipe
0       1        0         0          1B
1       2        0         0          2B
2       0        1         0          1C
3       1        1         0      1B, 1C
4       2        1         0      2B, 1C
5       0        2         0          2C
6       1        2         0      1B, 2C
7       2        2         0      2B, 2C
8       0        0         1          1P
9       1        0         1      1B, 1P
10      2        0         1      2B, 1P
11      0        1         1      1C, 1P
12      1        1         1  1B, 1C, 1P
13      2        1         1  2B, 1C, 1P
14      0        2         1      2C, 1P
15      1        2         1  1B, 2C, 1P
16      2        2         1  2B, 2C, 1P
17      0        0         2          2P
18      1        0         2      1B, 2P
19      2        0         2      2B, 2P
20      0        1         2      1C, 2P
21      1        1         2  1B, 1C, 2P
22      2        1         2  2B, 1C, 2P
23      0        2         2      2C, 2P
24      1        2         2  1B, 2C, 2P
25      2        2         2  2B, 2C, 2P
```

As desired.

Comment: That's however not a very practical approach, imagine if you have 100 columns

Comment: I agree that your approach is a lot cleaner for larger DataFrames. I still feel this answer is valuable to the OP, as while this original approach is inefficient, it is functional, except for some details that require attention. Still, it is important to acknowledge this is not the best possible approach.

Comment: The ```.apply()``` solution is closer to my current level of Python knowledge - as in, it's easier for me to understand how it works and why my original code didn't.
The ```.melt.query.pipe.groupby.agg.reindex``` approach is something I plan to read up on later, after the task is finished.

Comment: @AlexanderZorin I also provided an `apply` approach ;)